# Show and hide listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to do list view like this. What I want is when user touch 1st item, the 2nd item row appear. When user touch 3rd row item the previous item automatically hide again. How can i achieve this instead of using expandable listview? guide me in achieving this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry that i'm a bit busy, so i can't write the code right now. But below is the way which you can use to get what you want. I will add code when i will get time.

1. There is a parameter name "**android:animateayoutchanges**", apply it to the parent of your view which will be visible and invisible.
2. Save the position of the item which you have clicked and expanded.
3. When you click that item, Set the visibility of the view to visible.
4. When you again click on that item position, set that item's visibility to gone.
5. When you click some other item, then set the visibility of the stored item position to gone, set currently selected item's visibility to visible and store it's position.
   That's it.

**android:animateayoutchanges** is used so that when you set the visibility to visible or gone and views move upward or downward, then this movement will have smooth animation.

I will update my answer with code later But you will get an idea from above steps.

**UPDATE**

```
    public class ShippingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShippingAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ShippingOptions> list;
    private int expandedPosition = -1;
    private int listSize = 0;
    private int checkedPositon = -1;
    private String currency;

    public ShippingAdapter(ArrayList<ShippingOptions> list, String currency, AdapterInterface listener) {
        this.list = list;
        listSize = list.size();
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_shipping_options, parent, false);
        // Layout in which you will add **android:animatelayoutchanges**
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ShippingOptions item = list.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(item.getName());
        holder.fee.setText(utils.getFormattedCurrency(currency, Double.parseDouble(item.getShippingFee())));
        holder.description.setText(item.getDescription());
        holder.deliveryTime.setText(item.getDeliveryTime());
        if (listSize == 1) {
            list.get(position).setExpanded(true);
        }


        **if (list.get(position).isExpanded()) {
            holder.expandableView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (checkedPositon == position) {
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                holder.parent.setElevation(12);
                holder.parent.setTranslationZ(6);
                holder.parent.setClipToPadding(false);
                holder.parent.setClipToOutline(false);
            }
        } else {
            holder.expandableView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                holder.parent.setElevation(0);
                holder.parent.setTranslationZ(0);
            }
        }**

        **holder.parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listSize > 1) {
                    if (expandedPosition == position) {
                        if (list.get(position).isExpanded()) {
                            list.get(position).setExpanded(false);
                        } else {
                            list.get(position).setExpanded(true);
                        }
                        notifyItemChanged(position);
                    } else {
                        if (expandedPosition >= 0) {
                            list.get(expandedPosition).setExpanded(false);
                            notifyItemChanged(expandedPosition);
                        }
                        expandedPosition = position;
                        list.get(expandedPosition).setExpanded(true);
                        notifyItemChanged(expandedPosition);
                    }
                }
            }
        });**


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView name, fee, description, deliveryTime;
        public LinearLayout parent, expandableView;
        public CheckBox checkBox;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_shipping_name);
            fee = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_shipping_fee);
            description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
            deliveryTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_delivery_time);
            parent = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.parent);
            expandableView = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.expandable_view);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        }


    }
}
```

**list_shipping_options.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_shipping_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/text_medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="false"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/expandable_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/label_shipping_fee" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_shipping_fee"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/lable_description" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_description"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/delivery_time" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_delivery_time"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ShippingOptions.class**

```
    public class ShippingOptions implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String shippingFee;
    private String description;
    private String deliveryTime;
    private boolean isExpanded;
    private boolean isChecked;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getShippingFee() {
        return shippingFee;
    }

    public void setShippingFee(String shippingFee) {
        this.shippingFee = shippingFee;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDeliveryTime() {
        return deliveryTime;
    }

    public void setDeliveryTime(String deliveryTime) {
        this.deliveryTime = deliveryTime;
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return isExpanded;
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        isExpanded = expanded;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        isChecked = checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean update ths parameter on activity xml ?"android:animateayoutchanges"

Comment: yes, add this parameter in your list item's layout and set it to true

Comment: how to do step number 2?what do you mean by save the item position?

Comment: I believe you are new in android programming, you will get the position of the particular item which you have clicked. Save that position in an int variable

Comment: yes, im so newbie. android:animatedlayoutchanges on listview right?;)

Comment: Not on listview but on the layout that you are setting on list items. I see that you are not using custom adapter. You have to use a custom adapter. I will post sample code later. It's hard to understand it this way.

Comment: i have updated my answer and added the sample code. Please check

Comment: list_shipping_option on new xml?

Comment: Yes. I suggest you to look at code samples about how to create custom adapter. Then you will understand the above code.